# is there a way to disable github action check for self-hosted runner label check

Tags: github, github-actions

**is there a way to disable github action check for self-hosted runner label check ** :

vagrant@xx:~$ cat .github/workflows/integ_tests_wc.yaml | sudo docker run --rm -i rhysd/actionlint:latest -color -
<stdin>:79:28: label "ops" is unknown. available labels are "windows-latest", "windows-2022", "windows-2019", "windows-2016", "ubuntu-latest", "ubuntu-20.04", "ubuntu-18.04", "macos-latest", "macos-11", "macos-11.0", "macos-10.15", "self-hosted", "x64", "arm", "arm64", "linux", "macos", "windows". if it is a custom label for self-hosted runner, set list of labels in actionlint.yaml config file [runner-label]

Please avoid answering on how to created labels for self-hosted runner, Can we disable it, something similar to : #shellcheck disable=SC2086

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is very poorly phrased/formatted and doesn't show user effort.

Comment: But the answer is no. As your error message says, you need to setup your actionlint.yaml

Comment: Thanks @rethab , all i wanted is the answer you gave me which is : No (my team members are already working on setting up lables and failing for long time).  And about poorly phrasing, i like to keep the things simple (its a technichal forum, not a PHD thesis where you are expecting detailed explanation)

Comment: That's okay. Just some hints on the phrasing to improve future questions: (1) no formatting used, (2) the one relevant tool (actionlint) not mentioned except in the error message. Here are some tips on how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.